# PgAdmin4 download files

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Is there any way to download the backup files saved on the server's file system by pgadmin4 server. The best way I thought was to make the files available through Apache, but this solution has problems with authentication, or leaving the files public or requiring a new password.

Comment: I don't think there is an option to download files from the server through pgAdmin4, You can use 3rd party tools like `SCP` to download the files from web server.

Comment: I also did not find anything on pgAdmin4. I think I'll need to choose one of these alternatives.

Comment: I just send a new feature suggestion to the comunity.

Comment: The suggestion link: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3318

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was implemented in version 4.28.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Store Manager to download backup files from pgadmin.

You can access it from Menu -> Tools -> Store Manager.

From the docs,

> Storage Manager is a feature that helps you manage your systems
> storage device. You can use Storage Manager to:
>
> - Download, upload, or manage operating system files. To use this    feature, pgAdmin must be running in Server Mode on your client
>   machine.
> - Download backup or export files (custom, tar and plain text format)    on a client machine.
> - Download export dump files of tables.